# How can I make a Msgbox pop up over other application?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, macros

I have an Excel macro that deals with thousands of lines in several tables and do some copy/paste/analyze/combine... operations. it takes almost 10minutes to run it fully.

I added a `MsgBox "Job Done"` at the end, the thing is that the popup appears only if Excel is the active window. If I am for instance in Outlook, the popup won't pop up, limiting greatly its advantage.

Can I set something up so that it pops up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think out of the box. There are other ways to get your attention beside *Msgbox*

#### Popup a command line window [which is on top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/gg278437(v=office.15).aspx)

```
Sub Sample()
  RetVal = Shell("CMD /k echo Hello World", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

<sup>Note: This doesn't stop your VBA macro. Its running as a separate process</sup>

#### Play a [beep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz27k38z(v=vs.90).aspx) sound

```
Sub Sample()
  Beep
End Sub
```

<sup>Note: [*Default beep*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ralw0.png) must have a sound associated for this to work</sup>

#### Open notepad to gain attention

```
Sub Sample()      
  Set WScript = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  WScript.Run "%windir%\notepad", 1
End Sub
```

<sup>Read more on the great article [Programming the Windows Script Host](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1187429&seqNum=5). Focus behavior can be changed with [intWindowStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx)</sup>

Comment: I like the first solution, especially that it is not stopping the macro, can be as well used to mark some steps while running the code during the dev stage

Comment: @Memes I just want to mention that the third method also doesn't pause/stop the macro

Comment: Yes, I got that, but it is far less elegant: a "normal" user might just end up saying "hey, what the f$&%, I did not open notepad!!!"

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
vbSystemModal   4096    System modal; all applications are suspended until the user responds to the message box.
```

See [MsgBox Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082(v=vs.60).aspx)